# Sci-Fi movie, about binary code, aliens, and headaches

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show

It has been a long time I am trying to identify a movies I've seen but can't remember the title. I may have seen it in the late 90's or early 2000's. I saw it on TV in France.

It's very vague, but here it is all the details I remember.

- It's about a woman who hears voices all the time, saying only 0, 1 or 2.
- Other people think she is mad (related or not, can't tell).
- She feels better when she writes what she hears.
- At one time, someone suggest to pin all her papers on a wall.
- They identify it is binary code, but gets puzzled at the 2's.
- When they connect the 2's it forms a drawing.
- The drawing represents the Pioneer plaque with an extra character on it.

Can't remember anything else.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's the episode [The Message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Message_(The_Outer_Limits)) of *The Outer Limits* TV show:

From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_plaque#In_popular_culture) about Pioneer plaque:

> In "The Message," an episode of the science fiction series The Outer
>   Limits, a deaf woman was featured receiving alien signals through her
>   cochlear implant, prompting her to write out Xs, 1s, and 0s on paper.
>   When put together, the Xs turned into the images of the man and woman
>   from the plaque, along with an extraterrestrial humanoid raising a
>   hand in a peaceful gesture.

Comment: @mirage I only found it because I didn't know what the Pioneer plaque is :-) It turned out I did know, I only wasn't aware that it's called this way.

Comment: As an alternative,  this is a major plot point in Contact.

Comment: Not only am I blown away by how good you people are at identifying movies based on sketchy descriptions -- but also your response time is incredible! This is such a great SE.

Comment: @KlaymenDK Thanks, although this one was in fact very easy to find - there aren't that many movies and shows that have Pioneer plaque as a plot device. Plus, as mentioned above, it was really incidentally. Generally most of my IDs answers are for the movies and shows I know, so if I didn't get curious about an unknown term I would have skipped this one.